# Why does the order of the editor type entries flip upside down?

Tags: interface

When there's not enough space above the button, the entries switch order. Where you would have moved up 5 entries for the NLA-Editor, now you move 5 down. Is there a reason for that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason would be considered consistency. As menus are intended to be a mouse driven UI element, having the same option two steps from the mouse click is considered consistent. This changes when a user uses keyboard navigation as the direction to move changes depending on the location the menu starts.

The [`use_directional_menus`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UserPreferencesView.html#bpy.types.UserPreferencesView.use_directional_menus) option defines which order menus are drawn. When disabled menu items will always be in the same order, top to bottom.

This option isn't made visible to the user, so it needs to be set manually. Using blender's [Python Console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/python_console.html) type in

```
C.user_preferences.view.use_directional_menus = False
```

If you want this option to always be set, set the option and then in preferences click [*Save User Settings*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/introduction.html#save-user-settings)

Comment: That python command is amazing. That's why I accepted the answer (:

Comment: There is one reasoning, I just realised, even though it's not consistency: The devs probably thought that having the most used editors always visible without scrolling would be a good idea and that has some merit. But that's also achievable by always displaying the bottom of the list and letting the scolling always happen on top.

Answer (score 1):

Just another UI design as you are maybe used to.
In both of them you move 5 steps from your first click. For me this is also more natural.

Comment: I am using Blender since version 2.12, So, getting used to has nothing to do with it. How is having to check direction every time you want to do something more natural?

Comment: @Haunt_House 2.12... really?

Comment: I can see this being unnatural if you were using arrow keys to move up and down the menu, but with the mouse I just don't get it. I don't want to have to move the mouse four times as far because I open the menu in an opposite orientation as I did last time. It's the same idea as radio menus where correspondence to the place you clicked is important Point rather than exactly what's drawn on the screen. I really wish the rest of the world's interfaces did this...

Comment: Iam not used to keyboards, I am used to paper. If I remember that an item was on top of the list, the item should stay on top of the list. Everything else negates my memory in basically unexpected ways since I consider the question whether a menu still has enough space as completely irrelevant to the menu order. Do the same reasoning for a pie menu. For me, the list is a static object and I don't care whether I have to use the mouse for half an inch or a full inch and I have trouble seeing it being different for others.

Comment: @cegaton yes, 2000, 2001 with the printed 1.8 manual and the juicy Blender tuts was my starting point, why?

Comment: It's a bit like saying: the bakery is 200 yards south. But on tuesdays and the birthdays of some famous people, it's 200 yards north. Simply remember 200 yards and you're fine. No, you're not. The only real argument would be performance tests with a few hundred fresh people, measuring the time needed to pick menu items.